# Send message taken from Spy++

Tags: c#, pinvoke, sendmessage, spy++

I am trying to send a message to a game (to automate text commands), the problem is that I can't figure out how to use the information from spy++ to write a C# sendmessage function.

I was able to use spy++ to get
`00220540 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:0024052C nHittest:HTCLIENT wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE`

Could anyone provide a breakdown of what this means, and how to send the message to the game in c#?

EDIT:

I found out that I was looking at the wrong process. Instead of looking at the javaw.exe, I was looking at the actual game.

Here is the code for pressing t:

```
<00919> 0038062A WM_INPUT nInputCode:RIM_INPUT hRawInput:189E0973
<00920> 0024052 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'T' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:14fExtended:0fAltDown:0fRepeat:1fUp:1
```

Comment: which C# SendMessage function? State the full .Net class.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I will post what I was using, but I can easily change it, if somebody posts a different solution.

Comment: Considering the latest edits, is there still a question here? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So lets start with the signature for [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx), from [Pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

It taks a window handle, hWnd, a message ID, Msg, and two generic parameters wParam and lParam which change meaing based on the message ID.

What spy++ is showing you is the parameters that were sent to SendMessage.  As you can see it doesn't show you wParam and lParam, but hwnd, nHittest, and wMouseMsg.  That's because Spy++ knows what the wParam and lParam parameters actually mean for a [WM_SETCURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648382(v=vs.85).aspx) message and is decoding them for you.

So decoding each piece of the what Spy++ has sent:

1. `00220540` - the window handle receiving the message - the hWnd parameter.
2. `S` - It means it was sent via
   SendMessage() and not posted via
   [PostMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(VS.85).aspx).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265147(v=vs.60).aspx
3. `WM_SETCURSOR` - The message ID - the
   Msg parameter.
4. `hwnd:0024052C` - handle of the Window
   containing the cursor - the wParam
   parameter.
5. `nHittest:HTCLIENT` - the hit test
   code - the low word of the lParam
   parameter.
6. `wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE` - the mouse
   message - the high word of the
   lParam parameter.

The way you would go about sending the message to a window is:

```
enum WindowMessages {
    WM_SETCURSOR  = 0x0020,
    WM_MOUSEMOVE  = 0x0200,
    ....
}

enum HitTestCodes {
    HTCLIENT = 1,
    ....
}

....
IntPtr hWnd = [get your window handle some how]
int lParam = ((int)WindowMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE) << 16 + (int)HitTestCodes.HTCLIENT;
SendMessage(hWnd, (uint)WindowMessages.WM_SETCURSOR, hWnd, (IntPtr)lParam);
```

For understanding what other messages mean you can do a search on Msdn.com for the messsage in the Windows documentation.

So after answering all of that I don't think this will have anything to do with sending keys to the game you are trying to control.  WM_SETCURSOR doesn't have anything to do with keyboard input.

Comment: Thanks for the brake down, that is very helpful.  The game is coded in java.  When I press t (to bring up the message area), it gives the above message.  But when I type, I get nothing.  Could this be going through the java runtime?

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with the java runtime.  Sending fake keyboard and mouse input is not a reliable process on Windows.  The only thing I could suggest is making sure that the correct window has focus before calling SendKeys - since input is always sent to the focused window.

Comment: I modified my post, I was looking at the wrong process, if you could explain that message, I would be very greatful.

Comment: You can decode what the messages mean by searching for the WM_INPUT and WM_KEYUP message ID's.  Receiving a WM_INPUT may means that it uses raw input which is why SendKeys isn't working.  In any case you can't (reliably) send key strokes via window messages: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/21/10107494.aspx